# How to install a shortcut on the keyguard?

Tags: android, shortcut, lockscreen, keyguard

I am working on a school project and my app needs to have a shortcut on the keyguard (lockscreen).

So far I've found how to add a shortcut to the homescreen but I haven't found a way to install a shortcut on the keyguard. Can someone help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is to create a widget that you can place on the keyguard. This widget would be just a button with an intent in it.

This tutorial on widgets is really good : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidWidgets/article.html

And on the same website for intents so you know how to make your button be a link : http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html